# Kotlin: Superclass is not accessible from trait

Tags: traits, kotlin

In Kotlin, given some class:

```
public open class A {
    open fun sayHi() = "hi"
}
```

And a trait T that requires subclasses to extend A :

```
public trait T : A {
    override fun sayHi() = super.sayHi() + " John"
}
```

One would expect `T.sayHi` to be able to call `super.sayHi()` or the more explicit `super<A>.sayHi()`, since all the type information is there , but instead it yields `Superclass is not accessible from trait`.

**Question:**

[How] can I override some method from within the trait?

**Notes:**

Of course, without overriding I could just do:

```
public trait T : A {
    fun another() = sayHi() + " John"
}
```

But I do want my trait to be able to "intercept / be in the middle".

I had to use some delegate in order to achieve a similar behavior, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do this using traits.

Comment: The "required class in trait" feature is beeing deprecated and will eventually be removed from Kotlin. Have a look at http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/upcoming-changes-and-more/

Comment: oh, thanks for the update. Too bad, I was actually using that feature u__u
I find it useful to explicitly declare the requirements my trait has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Salomon poited out on his comment, this feature will be removed on newer versions of Kotin, making this question no longer valid.

> Required Classes
>
> Some of you might have heard of this feature: traits in Kotlin can
>   “extend” classes (we actually use the term “require”).
>
> Technically it means that when a class extends such a trait, it must
>   (directly or indirectly) extend the required class as well. This
>   feature has very few use cases, so we are deprecating it.

Source: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/upcoming-changes-and-more/